# Does there always exist a prime ideal that contains $x$ but not $y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity. Say $x, y$ are two distinct elements of $A$, neither of which are nilpotent. I was wondering can we always find a  prime ideal $P$ of $A$ such that $x \in P$ and $y \not \in P$? Thank you.

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb Z$, $x=21$, and $y=7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; if $x$ and $y$ differ by a unit, then they generate the same ideal, and so any prime ideal containing $x$ contains $y$, and vice-versa.

Suppose, though, that all prime ideals containing $x$ contained $y$, and vice-versa. Then $y$ is contained in all prime ideals of $A/(x)$, since the prime ideals of $A/(x)$ are the prime ideals of $A$ containing $x$. Since the intersection of all prime ideals of a ring is its nilradical, we have that $y$ is contained in the nilradical of $A/(x)$, i.e. $y \in \sqrt{(x)}$, the ideal of $A$ which is the radical of the ideal generated by $x$. If we swap $x$ and $y$, we can say that that $\sqrt{(x)} = \sqrt{(y)}$.

Comment: I should have thought about that more carefully. thank you. If $D(x) = D(y)$ what can we say about $x$ and $y$ in general? Would you happen to know? $D(x)$ is all the primes that does not contain $x$... I wanted to deduce $x = y$ somehow..

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain a condition which we can deduce from this; does this help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your help, in case you are interested this is the question I was trying to deduce by asking this question..  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430217/two-projections-of-a-ring-which-define-the-same-set-theoretic-map-of-the-the-spe