# Two projections of a ring which define the same set-theoretic map of the the Spec

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces

Suppose I have a commutative ring $A$ and an ideal $I$. 
And I have the projection $\pi: A \to A/I$ and suppose I have another ring morphism $\tau: A \to A/I$ and that $\pi^{-1} (P) = \tau^{-1}(P)$ for all primes $P$ of $A/I$. I'm wondering does this imply that $\pi = \tau$ or not? Either a proof or a counter example would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is true because the $Spec$ functor is an equivalence of categories between affine schemes and commutative rings.

Comment: @user347489: A morphism of affine schemes is more than just a function on the sets of prime ideals, though.

Comment: @EricWofsey oh right! I messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, if $A$ is a field and $I=0$, then $\pi$ is the identity map $A\to A/0=A$ but any other homomorphism $\tau:A\to A$ will also send the unique prime ideal $0$ to itself.

Comment: I thought the following was true: If I have an affine schme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and a closed subset with reduced induced subscheme structure $V(I)$, and closed immersions $\tau_1, \tau_2 : V(I) \to \operatorname{Spec} A$, where both are inclusion as a set-theoretic map, then $\tau_1 = \tau_2$... I think your answer shows that this is in fact not the case?

Comment: Indeed, that is false.